# HTML Position DIV Tag to the absolute TOP

Tags: css, html, position, absolute

```
.myDiv  
{

background-image: url(urltomyimgheader);

height:100px;

margin: auto;

position:relative;

top:-10px;

width:600px;

}
```

This is a simple div tag used to display the logo...

I have made the top -10px to make it touch the top of the browser where unless there is a gap between the logo and the page.

However i feel bad about using the -10px to position the div :( Is there a better and cross browser compatible solution?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Tatu Ulmanen is right that this is a browser default issue. You shouldn't have to add negative margins, you simply need to set the default CSS attribute of the body/html tags.

Just to be safe you should be using a CSS reset to get rid of Browser styling defaults anyways. Here's the code you can use to solve your problem. Below that is a nice CSS Reset you can add to the top of all your CSS stylesheets from here on out.

```
html, body {
padding: 0;
margin: 0;
}
```

CSS Reset:
    /*  Reset */

```
    html, body, div, span, applet, object, iframe,
    h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p, blockquote, pre,
    a, abbr, acronym, address, big, cite, code,
    del, dfn, em, font, img, ins, kbd, q, s, samp,
    small, strike, strong, sub, sup, tt, var,
    dl, dt, dd, ol, ul, li,
    fieldset, form, label, legend,
    table, caption, tbody, tfoot, thead, tr, th, td
                        { margin: 0; padding: 0; border: 0; outline: 0; font-weight: inherit; font-style: inherit; font-size: 100%; font-family: inherit; vertical-align: baseline; }
    blockquote:before,
    blockquote:after,
    q:before, q:after   { content: ""; }
    blockquote, q       { quotes: "" ""; }
    body                { line-height: 1; color: black; background: white; }
    caption, th, td     { text-align: left; font-weight: normal; }
    :focus              { outline: 0; }
    table               { border-collapse: separate; border-spacing: 0; }
    ol, ul              { list-style: none; }
```

Comment: Thanx a lot! :) Never knew the reset style sheet was this important :)

Answer (score 1):

Yes, the 10px gap is generated by default paddings of the browser for certain elements.

```
body {
   padding: 0;
}
```

You might also want to look into CSS reset stylesheets to reset all browser specific settings for elements. [Here's a good one](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/).

Comment: Thanx Tatu :) I have seen the Reset style sheets many time but i got to know the importance only now :)